# Duplicate Entire MySQL Database

Tags: mysql, database, linux

Is it possible to duplicate an entire MySQL database on a Linux server ?

I know I can use export and import but the original database is > 25MB so that's not ideal.

Is it possible using Mysqldump or by directly duplicating the database files?

Answer (score 189, accepted):

First create the duplicate database:

```
CREATE DATABASE duplicateddb;
```

Make sure the user and permissions are all in place and:

```
 mysqldump -u admin -p originaldb | mysql -u backup -pPassword duplicateddb;
```

Comment: I don't think there should be a space between "-p" and "password" in the 2nd part of your 2nd command line

Comment: If you want to duplicate all databases (including the `mysql` system database holding user details, etc.) you'll also want to use the `--all-databases` option on the mysqldump command, rather than specifying a particular database.

Comment: no the space should not be there! The Answer is correct like this. The mysql man page said: --password[=password], -p[password]

           The password to use when connecting to the server. If you use the short option form (-p), you cannot have a space between the option and the password. If you omit the
           password value following the --password or -p option on the command line, mysql prompts for one.

           Specifying a password on the command line should be considered insecure. See Section 6.1.2.1, "End-User Guidelines for P...

Comment: Note that mysqldump backs up by default the triggers but not the stored procedures, add `--routines` as an option for this case.

Comment: If you're doing it like this and you don't want this user's MySQL password to be available in the bash history, edit it out of your `~/.bash_history` file after executing it. Or you can also output the result of the first command to a temporary file and execute the following after it (which will prompt you with the password) `mysql -p -u admin duplicatedb < temporaryfile.sql`.

Comment: If you want to exclude certain tables from being copied, you can use `--ignore-table=database.tablename`

Comment: this method seems to bit slow. Any Idea? If I follow Import export method that works faster than this.

Comment: This answer certainly works, but question states "I know I can use export and import but the original database is >25MB so that's not ideal" and what this answer suggests is basically export and import.

Comment: works fine, if you got access denied error enter password like this 

`-p'your_password'`

password in single quote no space between p and password

Comment: In my case maria db i had error of unknown db with name of my backup db appear that there is semicolon in the end i removed and WORKED

Comment: mysqldump --host=localhost --user=root --password=123 originaldb | mysql --user=root --password=123 duplicateddb_bak;

Comment: `mysqldump -u username -p old_DB | mysql -u username -pPASSWORD new_DB;` this worked for me

Answer (score 20):

To remote server

```
mysqldump mydbname | ssh host2 "mysql mydbcopy"
```

To local server

```
mysqldump mydbname | mysql mydbcopy
```

Comment: ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax;, hi showing error while using command in local server, please help

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23446377/syntax-error-due-to-using-a-reserved-word-as-a-table-or-column-name-in-mysql

Answer (score 6):

I sometimes do a mysqldump and pipe the output into another mysql command to import it into a different database.

```
mysqldump --add-drop-table -u wordpress -p wordpress | mysql -u wordpress -p wordpress_backup
```

Comment: I get an error that the dest database doesn't exist when I use this.  So, you need a CREATE DATABASE line as well.

Comment: Doesn't this "move" the database instead of creating a copy? "--add-drop-table" sounds like it would delete the original database.

Comment: @FelixDolderer all that does is add commands to drop the tables and re-add them to the output from mysqldump which does those actions on the destination

Answer (score 4):

Create a mysqldump file in the system which has the datas and use pipe to give this mysqldump file as an input to the new system. The new system can be connected using ssh command.

```
mysqldump -u user -p'password' db-name | ssh user@some_far_place.com mysql -u user -p'password' db-name
```

no space between -p[password]

Comment: Could you add a description of how this works, e.g. the use of the pipe?

Answer (score 3):

**Making a Copy of a Database**

```
# mysqldump -u root -p password db1 > dump.sql
# mysqladmin -u root -p password create db2
# mysql -u root -p password db2 < dump.sql
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's a windows bat file I wrote which combines Vincent and Pauls suggestions.  It prompts the user for source and destination names.

**Just modify the variables at the top to set the proper paths to your executables / database ports.**

```
:: Creates a copy of a database with a different name.
:: User is prompted for Src and destination name.
:: Fair Warning: passwords are passed in on the cmd line, modify the script with -p instead if security is an issue.
:: Uncomment the rem'd out lines if you want script to prompt for database username, password, etc.

:: See also: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1887964/duplicate-entire-mysql-database

@set MYSQL_HOME="C:\sugarcrm\mysql\bin"
@set mysqldump_exec=%MYSQL_HOME%\mysqldump
@set mysql_exec=%MYSQL_HOME%\mysql
@set SRC_PORT=3306
@set DEST_PORT=3306
@set USERNAME=TODO_USERNAME
@set PASSWORD=TODO_PASSWORD

:: COMMENT any of the 4 lines below if you don't want to be prompted for these each time and use defaults above.
@SET /p USERNAME=Enter database username: 
@SET /p PASSWORD=Enter database password: 
@SET /p SRC_PORT=Enter SRC database port (usually 3306): 
@SET /p DEST_PORT=Enter DEST database port: 

%MYSQL_HOME%\mysql --user=%USERNAME% --password=%PASSWORD% --port=%DEST_PORT% --execute="show databases;"
@IF NOT "%ERRORLEVEL%" == "0" GOTO ExitScript

@SET /p SRC_DB=What is the name of the SRC Database:  
@SET /p DEST_DB=What is the name for the destination database (that will be created):  

%mysql_exec% --user=%USERNAME% --password=%PASSWORD% --port=%DEST_PORT% --execute="create database %DEST_DB%;"
%mysqldump_exec% --add-drop-table --user=%USERNAME% --password=%PASSWORD% --port=%SRC_PORT% %SRC_DB% | %mysql_exec% --user=%USERNAME% --password=%PASSWORD% --port=%DEST_PORT% %DEST_DB%
@echo SUCCESSFUL!!!
@GOTO ExitSuccess

:ExitScript
@echo "Failed to copy database"
:ExitSuccess
```

### Sample output:

```
C:\sugarcrm_backups\SCRIPTS>copy_db.bat
Enter database username: root
Enter database password: MyPassword
Enter SRC database port (usually 3306): 3308
Enter DEST database port: 3308

C:\sugarcrm_backups\SCRIPTS>"C:\sugarcrm\mysql\bin"\mysql --user=root --password=MyPassword --port=3308 --execute="show databases;"
+--------------------+
| Database           |
+--------------------+
| information_schema |
| mysql              |
| performance_schema |
| sugarcrm_550_pro   |
| sugarcrm_550_ce    |
| sugarcrm_640_pro   |
| sugarcrm_640_ce    |
+--------------------+
What is the name of the SRC Database:  sugarcrm
What is the name for the destination database (that will be created):  sugarcrm_640_ce

C:\sugarcrm_backups\SCRIPTS>"C:\sugarcrm\mysql\bin"\mysql --user=root --password=MyPassword --port=3308 --execute="create database sugarcrm_640_ce;"

C:\sugarcrm_backups\SCRIPTS>"C:\sugarcrm\mysql\bin"\mysqldump --add-drop-table --user=root --password=MyPassword --port=3308 sugarcrm   | "C:\sugarcrm\mysql\bin"\mysql --user=root --password=MyPassword --port=3308 sugarcrm_640_ce
SUCCESSFUL!!!
```

Answer (score 1):

This won't work for InnoDB.
Use this workaround only if you are trying to copy MyISAM databases.

If locking the tables during backup, and, possibly, pausing MySQL during the database import is acceptable, *mysqlhotcopy* may work faster.

### E.g.

#### Backup:

```
# mysqlhotcopy -u root -p password db_name /path/to/backup/directory
```

#### Restore:

```
cp /path/to/backup/directory/* /var/lib/mysql/db_name
```

*mysqlhotcopy* can also transfer files over SSH (scp), and, possibly, straight into the duplicate database directory.

### E.g.

```
# mysqlhotcopy -u root -p password db_name /var/lib/mysql/duplicate_db_name
```

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me with command prompt, from OUTSIDE mysql shell:

```
# mysqldump -u root -p password db1 > dump.sql
# mysqladmin -u root -p password create db2
# mysql -u root -p password db2 < dump.sql
```

This looks for me the best way. If zipping "dump.sql" you can symply store it as a compressed backup. Cool! For a 1GB database with Innodb tables, about a minute to create "dump.sql", and about three minutes to dump data into the new DB db2.

Straight copying the hole db directory (mysql/data/db1) didn't work for me, I guess because of the InnoDB tables.

Answer (score 0):

For me the following lines of code did the trick

```
mysqldump --quote-names -q -u username1 --password='password1' originalDB | mysql -u username2 --password='password2' duplicateDB
```

Answer (score -2):

Once upon a time in MySQL you could just copy all the table files to another directory in the mysql tree

mysql cli - create database db2

linux cli - cp db1 db2

Comment: That only works with MyISAM, right? Good those bad old days are gone.

Comment: Good one for the history books, but not very useful anymore.