# Copy mysql database from mysql command line

Tags: mysql, sql

How do I copy `database1` to `database2` from the mysql command line?

I know that `mysqldump` is one option, or I can do

```
drop table if exists table2; 
create table table2 like table1;
insert into table2 select * from table1;
```

But, i won't want to do this manually for each table name. Is this possible?

**The key here is "from the mysql command line"**
`mysql> ...`

Comment: Just to be sure: does it "have" to be using the mysql command line? Is using `mysqldump` out of the question?

Comment: Yes, and thank you for asking. mysql command line is what i'm looking for, not a bash terminal

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Duplicate Entire MySQL Database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1887964/duplicate-entire-mysql-database)

Answer (score 9):

First create the duplicate database:

```
CREATE DATABASE database2;
```

Make sure the user and permissions are all in place and:

```
 mysqldump -u admin -p database1| mysql -u backup -pPassword database2;
```

You can also refer to the following link for executing this on mysql shell.

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/mysqldump-copying-to-other-server.html

Answer (score 1):

In a stored procedure, loop over the results of

```
SELECT table_name FROM information_schema.tables WHERE table_schema = 'sourceDB';
```

At each iteration, prepare and execute a dynamic SQL statement:

```
-- for each @tableName in the query above
CREATE TABLE targetDB.@tableName LIKE sourceDB.@tableName;
INSERT INTO targetDB.@tableName SELECT * FROM sourceDB.@tableName;
```

*Sorry, the MySQL syntax for stored procedure being a serious pain in the neck, I am too lazy to write the full code right now.*

*Resources:*

- *[`CREATE PROCEDURE`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/create-procedure.html)*
- *[`PREPARE` and `EXECUTE`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/sql-syntax-prepared-statements.html)*
- *[`CURSORS`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/cursors.html)*

Answer (score 0):

Mysqldump can be used from mysql command line also.

Using: **system  (\!): Execute a system shell command**.

**Query:**

system mysqldump -psecret -uroot -hlocalhost test > test.sql

system mysql -psecret -uroot -hlocalhost < test.sql