# Copy a mysql database using mysql query

Tags: mysql

Phpmyadmin have a function is "Copy database to"..
Is there any mysql query to write this function?
something like copy db A to a new db B.

Comment: You have to write script for that. Otherwise you can follow this: `mysqldump -u[user_name] -p[password] A > A.sql`


Before doing the following Create database B;

`mysql -u[user_name] -p[password] B < A.sql`

Comment: those is write in cmd right? there is no way to write a mysql query to do that?

Comment: yes in mysql command line interface.

Comment: thanks your command is working... find out that can use exe("commands") in php to run the command..

Answer (score 0):

First create the duplicate database:

```
CREATE DATABASE duplicateddb;
```

Make sure the user and permissions are all in place and:

```
 mysqldump -u[username] -p[password] | mysql -u[username] -p[password] duplicateddb;
```

ref: [Duplicate Entire MySQL Database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1887964/duplicate-entire-mysql-database)

Answer (score 0):

Try to use mysqladmin and mysqldump in CLI, it provides such a functionality:

[MySQL Documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/mysqldump-copying-database.html)

Some additional documentation, which could be useful for you:

[link1](http://mysqlserverteam.com/creating-and-restoring-database-backups-with-mysqldump-and-mysql-enterprise-backup-part-1-of-2/)

[link2](http://www.thegeekstuff.com/2009/01/15-practical-usages-of-mysqladmin-command-for-administering-mysql-server/)