# Issue to clone mysql DB

Tags: mysql

I try to clone my_db to my_db_clone. I followd [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1887964/duplicate-entire-mysql-database)  and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1887964/duplicate-entire-mysql-database)  but I get always

> ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the
>   manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right
>   syntax

I tried thise but none worked, I get always that error :

```
mysqldump -u my_user -p my_db | mysql -u backup -pmy_password my_db_clone

mysqldump my_db | mysql my_db_clone;

mysqldump my_db -u my_user -pMy_passwprd > dumpdb.sql;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [`mysqldump`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/mysqldump.html) utility runs in the shell. How are you invoking it? Based on your error message, it appears that you might be trying to run it in the mysql client.

Try it in the shell instead.

Comment: that was my mistake. Thank you, you saved my day